# Chrome flickering on Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome

simple (hopefully) question; I have a Dell XPS 13 with a Skylake processor, running Ubuntu 16.04. Some webpages cause flickering (namely Twitch); I have Googled solutions and came across hardware acceleration as an option to fix it, which worked but caused a lot of screen tearing and increased page load times. Any other suggestions on a solution?

Comment: Did you tried other browsers/versions? PS: previous versions caused the issue?

Comment: I did try Firefox. No issue there. Previous versions do this too it seems.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue as you after installing chrome on Ubuntu 16.04 and enabling GPU rasterization in chrome://flags fixed it for me. Hope this helps

Comment: I tried that (along with some other flags) and it simply moved the flickering to the UI of the browser, as opposed to the web page. But I may reinstall Ubuntu (went back to Windows for now) and attempt JUST that one later on today.


I did post this on Chrome's support forum (see link at end of comment).
https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/chrome/CtKF2BiskT8/ax6jvFw1AgAJ

Comment: Enabling GPU rasterization seems to somewhat reduce the flickering but definitely not eliminate it - it is still annoying enough for me to not use Chrome

Comment: chrome://flags/#enable-gpu-rasterization

Answer (score 8):

According to [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/CtKF2BiskT8/w8kz5kbAAQAJ) discussion, launching Chrome with following flags fixes the problem (it did solve it for me too):

```
--disable-gpu-driver-bug-workarounds --enable-native-gpu-memory-buffers
```

Comment: What are the respective chrome:flags?

Comment: I don't think there are any as of now but I might be wrong.

Comment: I have found [Override software rendering list](http://i.imgur.com/apGiYAY.png) to work.

Comment: I think this has worked on my Dell XPS 15 9550 also. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer is in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766725/annoying-flickering-in-16-04-lts-chrome). As the best answer there:

> "I disabled hardware acceleration for my browser from
>
> Settings > Advance Settings > System > uncheck the hardware
>   acceleration"

Answer (score 3):

After some research, I found a solution to this problem. It is working for me now.

I disabled hardware acceleration for my browser from

**Settings > Advance Settings > System** and unchecking **hardware acceleration**

I am using google-chrome-stable Version 50.0.2661.94 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 16.04

If you encounter scrolling lag and screen tearing, try

Go to: **chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling** and **Enable** it.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal as root and enter this command: `"sudo nano /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop"` and scroll down until you get to this line: `"Exec= chromium-browser"` Then add this two parameters  `"--disable-gpu-driver-bug-workarounds --enable-native-gpu-memory-buffers"` click Ctrl+O to save and Ctrl+X to exit.

Then enter this command as root again: `"sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf"` and add this lines

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "sna"
   Option      "TearFree"    "true"
   Option      "DRI"    "3"
EndSection
```

Ctrl+O and Ctrl+X.

Open chromium and write to address bar: `"chrome://flags/"` and enter.

```
Enable-zero-copy
Enable Override Software Rendering List
Enable Display 2D List Canvas
```

Finally open chrome settings and click on:

```
"Use hardware acceleration when available"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a Dell Inspiron 7559 and have had the same problem on and off for some weeks. I've tried all of the possible solutions I've found (most of which are mentioned above) in various configurations. Some stopped the tearing and flickering for a while or to some extent, but it always seemed to start again.

Some of the solutions actually broke my os (when I changed the xorg file data).

In the end, I switched to using Firefox as my main browser and admitted defeat.

(Edit): My issue seemed to stem not from Ubuntu but rather from the Nvidia drivers installed with Bumblebee.

Comment: "I gave up and used a different browser" isn't all that helpful for others trying to solve the issue. If nvidia driver/bumblebee was causing your problem, perhaps you could have solved the problem by disabling them?