# Annoying flickering in 16.04 LTS - Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, 16.04, flicker

I've upgraded from 4.4.0 to 4.4.8 and then 4.5.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit, and it's still happening.

At 4.5.2 it's even more frequent, and mainly in Chrome (haven't tried firefox or opera just yet). Every time I open a new web page. Any way to fix that, or is it a bug?

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
04:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XTX [Radeon HD 8890M / R9 M275X/M375X] (rev 81)
```

Cheers.

Comment: Same thing I experience on Ubuntu 14.04.4

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, specially while using facebook. That's too annoying.

Comment: just in case: flickering has gone when upgrading to 16.10, so you do not need any workarounds anymore. just to mention

Comment: Try `--disable-gpu-driver-bug-workarounds  --enable-native-gpu-memory-buffers`   some extra info here : https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/CtKF2BiskT8;context-place=forum/chrome

Comment: Googler here. This bug is being tracked in the Chromium issue tracker at [#606152 - Flickering on Intel with one-copy uploads](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=606152).

Answer (score 205, accepted):

After some research, I found a solution to this problem. It is working for me now.

I disabled hardware acceleration for my browser from

`Settings > Advance Settings > System > uncheck the hardware acceleration`

Hope this works on your machine.

---

I am using `google-chrome-stable Version 50.0.2661.94 (64-bit)` on `Ubuntu 16.04`

**-----EDIT----**

If you encounter scrolling lag and screen tear. Do as suggested by [Amos Folarin](https://askubuntu.com/users/134660/amos-folarin) in the comment below:

Go to: `chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling` and Enable it.

Comment: I tried that, fixes the problem but makes my scrolling lag and screen tear.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, the flickering has dropped recently in the last few days to minimal. What could it be?

Comment: I found the hardware acceleration option disabled, enabled it and the flickering gone.

Comment: On my DELL XPS 15 9550 I had same issue as @Mookey . When disabling hardware acceleration my chrome started to be slow like a turtle, scrolling lag and screen tearing

Comment: This really shouldn't be accepted, as it's not a solution, it's definitely a work-around.

Comment: This has no effect on the flickering for me.

Comment: This solution worked for my XPS13 9343, the flickering definitely stopped or is not noticeable. I also tried the other solution suggested here setting chrome://flags/#enable-gpu-rasterization to  'Force-enabled for all layers' but this did not work, only disabling hardware acceleration in chrome seemed to work. But agree with @theV0ID that his is not idea.

Comment: Try also enabling chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling for smooth scrolling. I'm using XPS13 + Ubuntu16.04 works well with hardware accel option unchecked

Comment: Thank you @AmosFolarin , I edit the answer and included your tip.

Comment: Edited chrome flags and it works for me!  Thanks!

Comment: Disabling hardware acceleration has an awful effect on battery life!

Comment: This is actually a helpful setting when running Windows in a VirtualBox with the 3D drivers installed and enabled.  Chrome was flickering a ton, and this helped immensely.  Thank you!

Comment: Problem was solved though I LOST all of my passwords saved in chrome after clicking restart button that appeared in chrome after I unchecked the option

Comment: Hi, I have 4.4.0 kernel, 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit) Chrome and Intel integrated graphics. After disable hardware acceleration flickering of all window goes off, but instead I have flickering of some parts of the page, especially on facebook. But the real problem that now slack video calls in Chrome crashes.

Comment: To me it worked the other way around: I enabled hardware acceleration and then videos started playing as expected in YouTube.

Comment: gah, this was annoying. thanks so much!  Worked like a charm.  Note, I did both of these things, but it wasn't fixed until enabling the scrolling flag in the second part of this comment

Answer (score 161):

I had same problem, setting GPU rasterization to 'Force-enabled for all layers' seems to be finally working:

[image: Chrome Flags: GPU rasterization]

Comment: Seemingly only this one, or combination of this and everything else I tried before, solved my problem on Asus notebook UX305C. Eye saver!

Comment: quick link: chrome://flags/#enable-gpu-rasterization

Comment: worked for me too.

Comment: It stopped working, the flickering is back, I think after upgrading to Chrome Version 53.0.2785.92 (64-bit)

Comment: @Omid It's still working OK for me.

Comment: This decreased the flickering to some extent but still getting random flickers on Chrome 53.0.2785.116 unknown (64-bit).

Comment: This drastically reduces flickering, but it is still there in Google Inbox, for instance (currently the only place where I see it).

Comment: Works, but now only the left top corner of some images is being display. What did it for me was chrome://flags/#ignore-gpu-blacklist

Comment: Solved my problem for Chromium 58.

Comment: GPU Rasterization and Smooth scrolling are not working.

Answer (score 46):

I fixed it as follows:

```
sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

then reboot. This is because Intel drivers moved to modesetting. For more info see [this comment in the Chromium bug thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=606152#c73).

Comment: I went the chrome flags route and then went this route instead and reset the flags to default and purged the intel stuff.  So far, so good.

Comment: thanks. I have an Intel NUC which is a few years old and has gone through a few updates. It's on 16.04.2 but your suggestion did find packages to purge. It no longer flashes (my HDMI video was flashing on and off at about 1 or 2 Hz after some recent updates; I thought it had developed a hardware failure after 8 years of service).

Comment: Perfect for Linux Mint here :)

Comment: I can confirm that this solved the overall performance issues I had on my *Dell XPS 9350 + 17.10* :)

Comment: Dell Precision 5520 + Ubuntu 16.04 here, and I'm touching wood, because so far this seems like the solution (to _both_ my Slack and Chrome flickering problems)!

Comment: Dell XPS 13 9360, Ubuntu 16.04. I removed the driver, but I did not test tearing. After rebooting Chrome started to work slowly. Also I was not able to launch Road Redemption game. So I reistalled the driver.

Comment: Yes this fixes it. The other flags are some nice sugar but main issues are solved with this one on my macbook running linux mint 18

Comment: The accepted answer removes flickering but causes weird artifacting. This solved it for me on Linux Mint (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Joined the community to thank for this answer. Worked on debian 4.19.16-1~bpo9+1 (4.19.0-0.bpo.2-amd64).

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 37):

Open a terminal and enter this command:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop
```

and scroll down until you get to this line:

```
Exec= chromium-browser
```

Then add these two parameters

```
--disable-gpu-driver-bug-workarounds --enable-native-gpu-memory-buffers
```

Press Ctrl+O to save and Ctrl+X to exit.

Then enter this command:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
```

and add these lines

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "sna"
   Option      "TearFree"    "true"
   Option      "DRI"    "3"
EndSection
```

Press Ctrl+O then Ctrl+X.

Open Chromium and write to address bar: `chrome://flags/` and enter.

- Enable-zero-copy
- Enable Override Software Rendering List
- Enable Display 2D List Canvas

Finally open chrome settings and click on:

- Use hardware acceleration when available

Comment: Worked on my Dell XPS 15 95050 Intel® Core™ i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz Intel® HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2).

Comment: Having #enable-display-list-2d-canvas, . #enable-zero-copy and  #ignore-gpu-blacklist all to ENABLED seems to have fixed the flickering with a  HD Graphics 5500, intel-xorg 2.99.917.

Comment: In my case (after trying multiple solutions) I simply enabled those flags you mentioned (`zero-copy, Override Software Rendering List, Display 2D List Canvas`) and it seems to have fixed it (on Intel HD Graphics).

Comment: ixed the flickering on my Acer-574G with intel graphics 6th gen.

Comment: The two command line switches (disable workarounds/ enable native gpu memory buffers) don't seem to work anymore, but creating the `20-intel.conf` file worked for me! Also enabled gpu rasterization (not sure if it is important).

Comment: Just adding ``20-intel.conf`` worked for me - didn't have to do anything else.

Comment: The `20-intel.conf` fix works for me. The performance drop is noticeable though.

Comment: Also the only solution that worked for me (tried the top two answers). I'm on a desktop with a Radeon card and so I had to edit 10-radeon.conf and made sure to change the `Identifier` to `Radeon` and `driver` to `radeon`. Also, I'm using chrome stable and so my conf file was actually named `google-chrome.desktop`

Answer (score 27):

None of these answers seemed to help me. What I ended up doing which *seems* to have fixed it (My reference was this site http://www.bang-olufsen.com/ which flickered like CRAZY and now it works smoothly) is this:

1.- Navigated to `chrome://gpu/`. This is what it showed:

[image]

2.- I tried fixing the problems one by one. In my case, enabling these flags fixed some of them: `GPU rasterization`, `Override software rendering list`. Then it showed like this:

[image]

3.- I edited the desktop launcher and added the parameters `--disable-gpu-driver-bug-workarounds --enable-native-gpu-memory-buffers`.

4.- After that, no more problems detected, everything shows as "hardware accelerated" and, more importantly, no more flickering:

[image]

If you add the parameters to the launcher first, the list of problems should be shorter and it'll probably be easier to figure out which flags will help you with the problems you have left.

Comment: This is a good reference. I've used it to solve my problem with firefox, where it was simply solved by unticking "Use hardware acceleration" box in the advanced settings.

Comment: This reduced the flickering for me, but it still happens often...

Answer (score 7):

With Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit) the flags

```
--disable-gpu-driver-bug-workarounds --enable-native-gpu-memory-buffers
```

do not work anymore.

Best way we can do is step back to Chrome 50 (Version 50.0.2661.86 (64-bit)), here is an instruction how you can step back: [how do I downgrade google chrome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/485856/how-do-i-downgrade-google-chrome)

Important is that we put pressure on Google to fix this problem, vote for the bug in Chromium and on the google product page:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=606152

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/CtKF2BiskT8;context-place=forum/chrome

Comment: Does not work for me.

Comment: @ComBin : have you tried step back to v50 and used the flags ? However, follow the link to the chromium bug there are loads of different solution proposals to get this to work this current versions of chrome/-ium.

Comment: i dont want v50, thanks. I am found best way to fix it, see my answer bellow.

Comment: AHa , in the chromium bug the guys meant that this would have massive performance issues. However I will try some suggestions from the chromium bugs when I have the time, as far as I understood Chromium is only the symptom not the cause. I'll keep you updated if I find something better/other. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

```
chrome://flags/ > GPU rasterization > Enable,
```

This finally worked for me!
Found it at the bottom of this Google Form!
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/CtKF2BiskT8/dLXKfU2XAQAJ

Answer (score 4):

I think I found the solution:

flags  --disable-gpu-driver-bug-workarounds --enable-native-gpu-memory-buffers  and also enable-zero-copy ENABLE

```
    sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf
    Section "Device"
       Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
       Driver      "intel"
       Option      "AccelMethod"  "sna"
       Option      "TearFree"    "true"
       Option      "DRI"    "3"
    EndSection
```

Comment: There are some flags missing, here is my step by step: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=606152#c72

Comment: I was able to fix my issue with just the Section in the 20-intel.conf file with no additional flags in chrome on bionic beaver 18.04

Answer (score 2):

Try loading with some GPU options disabled:

--disable-gpu-driver-bug-workarounds --enable-native-gpu-memory-buffers

After you try that you can also fiddle with some of the rendering settings in about://flags and see if anything there helps, but the bulk of my render flickers were solved by the two command line flags. If you have a launcher .desktop file add those flags to the top Exec entry before the '%U'.  You can also add them to the other Exec entries to have the flags applied to all startup modes.

Answer (score 2):

I found the present fixes do not work for current version of chrome, further things need to be changed (at least for my setup).

I can confirm this works (removes both flicker and tearing) -- with thanks to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=606152#c72

Computer: XPS13 9343
Graphics: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
Chrome version: Version 54.0.2840.100 (64-bit)

Settings

1) Check the error messages before and after config adjustments below

- chrome://gpu
- take a screenshot so you can compare after.

2) Edit(for chrome): `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` or for (chromium): `/usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop`

- Add the flags --disable-gpu-driver-bug-workarounds --enable-native-gpu-memory-buffers
- line should look like this: `Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --disable-gpu-driver-bug-workarounds --enable-native-gpu-memory-buffers %U`

3) sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf  add this (you may need to create the file):

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "sna"
   Option      "TearFree"    "true"
   Option      "DRI"    "3"
EndSection
```

4) Chrome flags settings: chrome://flags:

- Enable ("zero copy rasterizer"): chrome://flags/#enable-zero-copy
- Enable (enable display list 2d canvas): chrome://flags/#enable-display-list-2d-canvas
- Enable ("Override software rendering list"): chrome://flags/#ignore-gpu-blacklist
- Enable "Display list 2D canvas"): chrome://flags/#enable-display-list-2d-canvas
- Enable (chrome flag for smooth scrolling in linux):  chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling

5) I kept the Chrome Setting> Advanced > Use Hardware Acceleration when available [**keep checked**]. If you unchecking this **really** hits performance (although does reduce flickering but not tearing), the above options worked much better for me.

6) Restart the computer.

7) Compare settings. chrome://gpu

This totally eliminated the flickering and tearing for me.

Comment: Actually, This could be answer.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling hardware acceleration will degrade your browsers performance for the pages having animations and other processor intensive tasks.

However, if you don't have any GPU installed in your system then the approach of disabling hardware acceleration suggested by [sgiri](https://askubuntu.com/a/768112) is best for you.

But I have an *NVidia* GPU installed in my laptop and I am using Ubuntu desktop OS.
So I installed the proprietary binary driver (version 352.63).  It worked for me, hope will work in your Ubuntu system too.