# Ubuntu 16.04 Laptop flickering problem

Tags: kernel, 16.04, hybrid-graphics, flicker

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed in my laptop. I use the default graphic driver. I have 2 graphic cards: integrated and Nvidia.

I saw some questions about this and I did update system kernel to last stable: 4.6.2.

The problem that I have is that in some applications like Vivaldi the screen flickers from time to time.

What can I do to fix this?

Thank you.

[EDIT]
Graphics:
 1. Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
 2. Nvidia Geforce 740m

PC: Toshiba Satellite L50-A-103

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about fixing this but could you please list your laptop model and both your integrated and Nvidia graphics card models? I believe that would be helpful.

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: I did a little research into flickering on 16.04. Some people seem to have solved their flickering by turning Bluetooth on. Idk how that fixed it but it's worth a try if your laptop has Bluetooth. [Source](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/os-applications/f/4613/t/19680410)

Comment: I have it disabled but I'm gonna try turn it on. Any other solutions?

Comment: What about the instructions in this other thread? [thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/766725/annoying-flickering-in-16-04-lts-chrome?rq=1)