# my laptop Is AMD hybrid-graphics card, is it supported by Ubuntu 16.04 driver?

Tags: drivers, graphics, fglrx, amd-graphics

so, I tried a clean install of 16.04 LTS, is there any way to find out whether my AMD graphics card is fully supported by the driver ? Cuz my screen is flickering

I'm not talking gaming, just the open source driver that is replacing the fglrx driver. I'm using a hybrid Intel/AMD system.

Here's my card:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0126] (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] [1002:6760] (rev ff)
```

Comment: See if you can disable the discrete graphics card (the AMD one) in BIOS. That'll make sure the Intel card is being used, which should work better in this case.

Comment: Did that. Same issue happens

Comment: check http://askubuntu.com/q/766725/329036

Answer (score 0):

Using the OS radeon driver make sure you pass nomodeset to the kernel boot parameters.

(see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters)