# Whatapp web constantly flickering

Tags: google-chrome, whatsapp

I am running Ubuntu 16.04

I started running whatsapp web for chrome today and the screen is constantly flickering.

It didn't happen earlier. Also it doesn't happen with Windows.

Why is it happening?

Comment: What GPU do you have? Did you installed any drivers for it? Could be a problem of Chrome (and causes that), or of the GPU driver.

Comment: I have AMD and Xenial doesn't support it officially anymore

Comment: Is possible that issue is caused by the GPU driver, because is not officially supported, and could have some strange incompatibilities with 16.04 and the Linux kernel.

Comment: I seriously doubt it as other things like flash videos, intensive video games are all working fine

Comment: Then, I only could think that Chrome has something weird while rendering WhatsApp Web. Did you tried with Firefox? The flickering happen in Firefox too?

Comment: However the app is available only in chrome web store. For Firefox it is out of reach.

Comment: In any browser, WhatsApp Web is accessible from http://web.whatsapp.com. Easy as that. Try it.

Comment: consider posting this as an answer

Comment: I wouldn't post it as an answer because it's a workaround and not a fix. I have this happening as well with an NVIDIA card. So it has something to do with Chrome itself and not a specific video driver.

This happens to me on Ubuntu and not Debian 8, so this is specific to Ubuntu + Chrome

Answer (score 0):

This answer fixed it for me: 
https://askubuntu.com/a/768112/190333

> I disabled hardware acceleration for my browser from
>   Settings > Advance Settings > System > uncheck the hardware acceleration

This is something to do with hardware accelleration on Ubuntu. In my case I am running 17.10 and using an NVIDIA card.

I switched to a machine with the exact same card and driver, but running Debian 8, and the problem did not exist.

So while we have a fix, this indicates a problem unique to Ubuntu + Chrome, and not the video drivers specifically.