# Chrome texts flickering on select

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, google-chrome, chromium

Chrome text flickering on select. I did everything mentioned at [Annoying flickering in 16.04 LTS - Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766725/annoying-flickering-in-16-04-lts-chrome) but didn't change anything.

I recorded my screen. so you can see how it's flickering. Look at "anyway":

[image: chrome text flickering]

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and chromium 52.0.2743.116 and Nvidia Driver 361.42 (Also 367.57). I also tried chrome 53 and the result was the same. Firefox doesn't have this problem.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Took me a bit to see it, but it looks like all the `a`s are flickering / bouncing when you are manipulating / highlighting the text.  I don't know of a fix at the moment, but I can try to do some research for you, or hopefully someone that will come along will know the answer to this.

Comment: @ElderGeek Look at `a`

Comment: @ElderGeek Just look at 'anyway' for 5 seconds

Comment: Been there, done that.

Comment: Before that, how does it matter?

Comment: @Peaceful I don't know what cause the flickering, but it's not just about highlighting the text. sometimes when a page loading some new stuff with AJAX the flickering can appear on other text too. Just like the flickering I recorded.

Comment: Have you tried turning hardware acceleration off?  Go to advanced setting and un-check that option.

Comment: @Juan Antonio Yes. I already mentioned that on my question. It can't fix the problem.

Comment: @ICE, have you tested disabling other features in `chrome://flags/`? like: Accelerated 2D canvas, Display list 2D canvas, Overlay Scrollbars, LCD text antialiasing, Distance field text.

Comment: @user.dz Disabled `LCD text antialiasing` and fixed the problem. You can  add that as answer and I'll accept it but the problem go further now! Texts being hard to read.

Comment: I would suggest keeping the question open and just vote mine up :) (it is a partial solution). So every reader know that you are still looking for solution, Someone may find a better one.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open this URL in Chrome `chrome://flags/`
2. Disable LCD text antialiasing