# Chrome: images with distorted lines

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

I have ubuntu 16.04 and google-chrome-stable installed. I had the blinking issue which I solved thanks to this post: [Annoying flickering in 16.04 LTS - Chrome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766725/annoying-flickering-in-16-04-lts-chrome) . Still, sometimes (usually when a page is loading) I get the following kind of distortion in images

[image]

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same problem with my Ubuntu 14.04.

So in order to prevent flickering we did:

1) Settings > Advance Settings > System > uncheck the hardware acceleration

2) Go to: chrome://flags/#smooth-scrolling and Enable it.

But this has a side effect in introducing distorted lines